# How to deploy a web application on Tomcat with SSL on Docker

Tags: spring, docker, ssl, tomcat, web-applications

I have a web application (.war) and want to deploy it on a tomcat server. Additionally the REST API communication should be through SSL and handover the docker image with all these changes.

Answer (score 1):

The process is divided in to small steps. Here are the steps to deploy a web app on docker with tomcat and SSL:

1. Generate key and crt files using OpenSSL and export it in PKCS12 format
2. Update server.xml with SSL configuration
3. Create a Dockerfile
4. Build image and run it in docker container
5. Export docker image file

Before we start, keep war file ready from the web application (not a spring boot app) which is going to be deployed.

If it is a maven project this command can help-

> mvn clean package

**Let's start:**

### Generate SSL key using OpenSSL and export it in PKCS12 format

***OpenSSL***

Download OpenSSL or if Git is installed on your system locate this path and double click

> C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe

A command prompt with OpenSSL will be opened.

There are multiple ways to create keys and certs like keytool, openssl. The more options the more confusion. I would recommend not to try multiple solutions as you may get stuck with errors while deploying on server.

Below are couple of commands that we can hit through OpenSSL and resulting file we can use as a keystore file.

```
req -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -out <path-to-save>\server.crt -keyout <path-to-save>\server.key -days 365
```

Provide passphrase which is the password of this key and provide other details on the console.

*We now have two files server.key and server.crt. Lets create PKCS12 format file*

```
pkcs12 -export -out <path-to-save>\server.p12 -inkey server.key -in server.crt
```

*server.p12 is the file that tomcat will use for SSL configuration*

### Update SSL configuration changes in Tomcat's server.xml

Get tomcat installed on your machine. The server.xml file can be located at

> <tomcat-installation-root-directory>\conf\server.xml

Add below code snippet inside <service> tag:

```
<Connector 
    port="8443" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"   
    maxThreads="150" 
    SSLEnabled="true" 
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true"           
    clientAuth="false" 
    sslProtocol="TLS"           
    sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" 
    keystoreType="PKCS12"
    keystoreFile="<server.p12-file-location>" 
    keystorePass="<passphrase-provided-while-generating-key>"
    />
```

Till now, we have created keystore file and configured tomcat with SSL configuration.

---

*To test if it working, copy war file inside \webapps directory and start tomcat by double click on \bin\startup.bat file*

Should be able to receive response from GET API through browser with https protocol. Since this is a self-signed certificate not provided by authorized third party, manually proceed on browser to hit the url.

### Generate Dockerfile

To run the application with SSL enabled tomcat on docker, a **Dockerfile** is required.

Sample Dockerfile with all required steps:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.5-jre8
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8443

#copy p12 file location to docker tomcat path
COPY ./ssl /usr/local/tomcat/ssl

#Copy updated server.xml to docker
COPY ./server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml

#Copy war file to docker tomcat \webapps folder
COPY ./target/WebAppHTTPS.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/WebAppHTTPS.war
```

Update your path accordingly or can follow this file structure to make it easily accessible.

```
|
|---ssl
|   |
|   |---server.p12
|
|---target
|   |
|   |---WebAppHTTPS.war
|
|---Dockerfile
|
|---server.xml
```

### Build Docker image and run it in container

Execute following commands to deploy the app on Docker container:

```
docker build -t <any-name-like-sslwebapp> <location-to-Dockerfile>
```

This will build a docker image while executing all commands provided in Dockerfile.

```
docker run -p 8443:8443 <name-provided-earlier-like-sslwebapp>
```

This command shows all logs on console. If there is no error press Ctrl+C and hit below command to run it in detach mode.

```
docker run -d -p 8443:8443 <name-provided-earlier-like-sslwebapp>
```

Hit GET API URL with https from browser. And this is how the SSL configuration is done.

### Export Docker image

This is to provide Docker image to your colleague or any one with out using any repo.

Execute below command to export image in .tar format

```
docker save -o \<path>\docker-image.tar sslwebapp
```

Here, sslwebapp is the name of the image tag we provided earlier.

Share this file and receiver can use below command to use this image

```
docker load -i \<tar-file-path>
```

Comment: Docker is retrurning error during start. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: keystore password was incorrect. While provided password is for sure correct